# Javascript onclick not

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

So I am creating a table dynamically with javascript.

I loop through an array of elements and I am making a table row for each element in the array.
I create the row by

```
let row = document.createElement('tr');

row.onclick = function() {console.log("On Click Working"};
```

But this is not working for me.
Outside of the loop I used jQuery to attach the onclick event handler to each row and that works. 
I am just curious to why the `row.onclick = ...` approach did not work? 
Does anyone have an explanation for this??

Comment: Show your code and do not mix it in with the text.

Comment: Minus the typo it should work, I think we need to see more code.

Comment: First step of debugging, alway crack open your browser console and look for errors.

Comment: Works fine http://jsbin.com/ruvecagavo/edit?html,js,output Debug the rest of your code

Answer (score 0):

Works fine if you put the ')' at the end of the console log and fix that syntax error.

```js
console.log('hey, im in whatever logic does this creation!');
let row = document.createElement('tr');
row.onclick = function() {console.log("On Click Working")};

row.click();
```

Comment: I didn't have that syntax error in the code.  I also went back and pasted the exact code you put up in there and it still didn't work.

Comment: Im sorry I am very new to stack overflow so I am unfamiliar with conventions.  I did not have the row.click() part inside of the loop.  I want to show to all of the loop code but there is not enough space to comment it.

Comment: Oh I always have the debugging console open and don't see ANY errors which is why I am so confused.  I have another function which attaches an event handler to a table row in that same fashion, and that works perfectly fine which is another reason why I am so confused.

Comment: So with the logic above verbatim in your code, which of the two console logs print, if either?

Comment: Only the first one, it prints every time there is a new element in the loop.

Comment: Ok yeah, that doesn't make sense then.  If the code is exactly the same as I have it, which works here, there should be nothing stopping that click event from working.  There are no other events attached to it that would possibly prevent it.

Comment: Right?? But if there's one thing I've learned it's that the computer will always behave as it is told so there has to be some other code effecting that onclick.

Comment: There should not be in this case.  Create element, attach handler, invoke event for handler.  There's nothing else going on inbetween those steps that should change anything, regardless of computer.  And if there are no console errors that would cause javascript to all together stop execution, it should work as expected.

Comment: @Taplar: Yes, it can have something else... For example, if the `tr` are `sortable` (jQuery-ui), the click event is prevented.

Comment: No dude. I said *verbatim*, meaning you take what I have, copy, paste, and see if it works.  If you change any of it and don't tell us, you are leaving out information which may lead us to the issue.  That's why I said do it verbatim.  If we say to try X and you try Y and then say X didn't work, you see where we can have problems? :)

Comment: @Taplar: Are you sure that OP speaks Latin? Below my answer, he said that there is 4 `td` inside the `tr`... So there certainly is something else.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette is that not a common word anymore?  :s

Answer (score 0):

Do you append the row to document?
Is there some content in it (So user can click on it)?

```js
let row = document.createElement('tr');

row.innerHTML = "<td>Click here</td>";
row.onclick = function() {console.log("On Click Working")};

document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].append(row);
```

```html
<table></table>
```

Comment: Yes there are 4 <td> elements in the row as well.

Comment: Well... Post ALL the relevant code, because no one can find what's the cause of your issue. What you posted works.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot attach an event listener just by assigning value to it.
You can attach by using the function addEventListner() into it.

```
row.addEventListener('click', function() { 
  console.log("On Click Working")
})
```

Now you need to append the element into the DOM.

```
document.body.appendChild(row)
```

you can use any DOM element with whom you want to append your element.

I hope this helps